# Producing a "fuzzy" RD plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460257/constraining-stat-smooth-to-a-particular-range) but the answers there will not work for me. Basically, I'm trying to produce a regression discontinuity plot with a "fuzzy" design that uses all the data for the treatment and control groups, but only plots the regression line within the "range" of the treatment and control groups.

Below, I've simulated some data and produced the fuzzy RD plot with base graphics. I'm hoping to replicate this plot with ggplot2. Note that the most important part of this is that the light blue regression line is fit using all the blue points, while the peach colored regression line is fit using all the red points, despite only being plotted over the ranges in which individuals were intended to receive treatment. That's the part I'm having a hard time replicating in ggplot.

I'd like to move to ggplot because I'd like to use faceting to produce this same plot across various units in which participants were nested. In the code below, I show a non-example using `geom_smooth`. When there's no fuzziness within a group, it works fine, but otherwise it fails. If I could get `geom_smooth` to be limited to only specific ranges, I think I'd be set. Any and all help is appreciated.

### Simulate data

```
library(MASS)
mu <- c(0, 0)
sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.7, 0.7, 1), ncol = 2)

set.seed(100)
d <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(1e3, mu, sigma))

# Create treatment variable
d$treat <- ifelse(d$V1 <= 0, 1, 0)

# Introduce fuzziness
d$treat[d$treat == 1][sample(100)] <- 0
d$treat[d$treat == 0][sample(100)] <- 1

# Treatment effect
d$V2[d$treat == 1] <- d$V2[d$treat == 1] + 0.5

# Add grouping factor
d$group <- gl(9, 1e3/9)
```

### Produce regression discontinuity plot with base

```
library(RColorBrewer)
pal <- brewer.pal(5, "RdBu")

color <- d$treat
color[color == 0] <- pal[1]
color[color == 1] <- pal[5]

plot(V2 ~ V1, 
    data = d, 
    col = color,
    bty = "n")
abline(v = 0, col = "gray", lwd = 3, lty = 2)

# Fit model
m <- lm(V2 ~ V1 + treat, data = d)

# predicted achievement for treatment group
pred_treat <- predict(m, 
            newdata = data.frame(V1 = seq(-3, 0, 0.1), 
                                 treat = 1))
# predicted achievement for control group
pred_no_treat <- predict(m, 
            newdata = data.frame(V1 = seq(0, 4, 0.1), 
                                 treat = 0))

# Add predicted achievement lines
lines(seq(-3, 0, 0.1), pred_treat, col = pal[4], lwd = 3)
lines(seq(0, 4, 0.1), pred_no_treat, col = pal[2], lwd = 3)

# Add legend
legend("bottomright", 
    legend = c("Treatment", "Control"),
    lty = 1,
    lwd = 2,
    col = c(pal[4], pal[2]),
    box.lwd = 0)
```

[image: fuzzy_RD_plot]

### non-example with ggplot

```
d$treat <- factor(d$treat, labels = c("Control", "Treatment"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(V1, V2, group = treat)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = treat)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(color = treat)) +
    facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image: ggplot_non_example]

Notice the regression lines extending past the treatment range for groups 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more graceful way to make the lines with `geom_smooth`, but it can be hacked together with `geom_segment`. Munge the data.frames outside of the plotting call if you like.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = factor(treat, labels = c('Control', 'Treatment')))) + 
    geom_point(shape = 21) + 
    scale_color_brewer(NULL, type = 'qual', palette = 6) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), color = 'grey', size = 1, linetype = 'dashed') + 
    geom_segment(data = data.frame(t(predict(m, data.frame(V1 = c(-3, 0), treat = 1)))), 
                 aes(x = -3, xend = 0, y = X1, yend = X2), color = pal[4], size = 1) + 
    geom_segment(data = data.frame(t(predict(m, data.frame(V1 = c(0, 4), treat = 0)))), 
                 aes(x = 0, xend = 4, y = X1, yend = X2), color = pal[2], size = 1)
```

[image: ggplot version]

Another option is `geom_path`:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(-3, 0, 0, 4), treat = c(1, 1, 0, 0))
df <- cbind(df, V2 = predict(m, df))

ggplot(d, aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = factor(treat, labels = c('Control', 'Treatment')))) + 
    geom_point(shape = 21) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), color = 'grey', size = 1, linetype = 'dashed') + 
    scale_color_brewer(NULL, type = 'qual', palette = 6) + 
    geom_path(data = df, size = 1)
```

[image: ggplot with geom_path]

---

For the edit with facets, if I understand what you want correctly, you can calculate a model for each group with `lapply` and predict for each group. Here I'm recombine with `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `do.call(rbind, ...)` for the `.id` parameter to insert the group number from the list element name, though there are other ways to do the same thing.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(-3, 0, 0, 4), treat = c('Treatment', 'Treatment', 'Control', 'Control'))
m_list <- lapply(split(d, d$group), function(x){lm(V2 ~ V1 + treat, data = x)})
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(m_list, function(x){cbind(df, V2 = predict(x, df))}), .id = 'group')

ggplot(d, aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = treat)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 21) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), color = 'grey', size = 1, linetype = 'dashed') + 
    geom_path(data = df, size = 1) + 
    scale_color_brewer(NULL, type = 'qual', palette = 6) + 
    facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image: facetted ggplot]

Comment: Thanks for the input. That works well for this single plot, but what I'm really hoping to do is use faceting to produce the plot for each group, so the model would change for each group. I've edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Perfect! Your edit is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hah, how lucky!

Comment: Shoot... actually, I got overly excited. It doesn't quite work because it's still using the same model for each group, whereas I actually need it to plot the fit from separate models for each group (i.e., what's going on in the non-example, but with the range of the fit restricted to only the treatment ranges).

Comment: Check out the edit. If I've understood what you want, it's mostly a data wrangling issue; it's easier to make the models outside of ggplot so you can control them how you like.

Comment: Beautiful! I'll test it out when I get back to my computer but it looks like this will work! I'd considered fitting all the models through a loop but thought there'd be an implementation in ggplot. Regardless, this is better than what I'd have come up with had I gone that route. Much thanks!

Comment: ... and indeed that did it! Thanks again. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: My pleasure, it was fun!